# $pull parameter not working with mongodb using nextjs typescript. I tried everything

Tags: arrays, typescript, mongodb, next.js, webrequest

I am trying to delete a certain array element from my array. It does not give any errors, actually the response is here:
`{"floormaps":{"acknowledged":true,"modifiedCount":0,"upsertedId":null,"upsertedCount":0,"matchedCount":1}}`
But nothing gets changed or modified.

Here is a picture of the database elements. I am trying to sort it with the "name" element.
[array elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVWFS.png)

And here is the code I use to delete the specific array. Hope someone had and fixed this issue before.
`let floormaps = (await db.collection("editor").updateOne({name: "Doruk"}, { $pull: { FloorMaps: { name: req.query.name as string } } }, ))`
and here is the web request I send
http://localhost:3000/api/database/delete?function=FloorMaps&name=test

I tried many ways with array filters but nothing seemed to work. I want to delete an element of the array based on it's name

Comment: `{ $pull: {'FloorMaps.name': req.query.name as string }`